# Free Java IDE with the best Maven integration

Tags: java, ide, maven-3

What is free Java IDE with the best Maven (esp. Maven 3) integration?

Comment: All three major Java IDE's (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans) support maven projects well.  This allows you to work with your code in any of them, depending on which tool you need at the moment.  This is a very powerful thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest Netbeans as it uses maven as its build system. i.e. the tightest integration.  However other IDEs such as IntelliJ and Eclipse also have excellent integration.

NetBeans and IntelliJ don't need a plugin for Maven support.

Comment: Has Netbeans functionality for generating dependency graphs?

Comment: IntellJ Ultimate has some excellent dependency visualisation tools, but is a commercial product. You can trial it for 30 days to see if does what you need.

Comment: netbeans is indeed an awesome ide and works well with maven

Comment: intelliJs integration of maven is somewhat special. they create giant indices, they do their own stuff with pluginregistries, which are cached in huge amounts of caches that neither eclipse nor netbeans need to function flawless. I feel, IntelliJ is a disease, not a cure.

Comment: @Manticore I agree that IntelliJ tends to use more memory, that is less of a problem these days with many dev machines having  SSD or better and 16-32 GB. I use a 64 GB desktop with an NVMe drive so I don't notice.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse or NetBeans provide a good support for maven. (Eclipse with plugin)
I found that the support for maven is in NetBeans better as it is in Eclipse.
In Eclipse you need the plugin m2eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse Indigo the maven support in has really improved.
note that the eclipse plugin is provided by "Sonatype" which support 
the maven project

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)  http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to go with eclipse IDE.